# Create generic async task function

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have created a function that returns an object using `async`/`await`. I would like to make the function generic so that it can return whatever object that I pass in. The code is boilerplate except for the objects being returned. I would like to be able to call GetAsync and have it return the correct object

```
public Patron getPatronById(string barcode)
{
    string uri = "patrons/find?barcode=" + barcode;
    Patron Patron =  GetAsync(uri).Result;
    return Patron;
}

private async Task<Patron> GetAsync(string uri)
{
    var client = GetHttpClient(uri);
    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Patron Patron = ser.Deserialize<Patron>(content);
    return Patron;
}
```

Comment: object is root object? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You shouldn't use `.Result` on the result of `GetAsync`. If you call it on the UI thread, you'll get a deadlock.

Comment: Why is `getPatronById` not async? It should either be async and you don't use `.Result` or `GetAsync` should not be async and you should use `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient` and use it's syncronous methods. Using `.Result` will likely cause your program to lock up.

Comment: Also a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on the `.GetStringAsync(uri)` would not hurt either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about a generic method?

```
private async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri)
{
    var client = GetHttpClient(uri);
    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var t = serializer.Deserialize<T>(content);
    return t;
}
```

Normally, you should place this method into another class and make it `public`, in order it can be used by methods in different classes.

Regarding the way you call this method, you could try the following:

```
 // I capitalized the first letter of the method, 
 // since this is a very common convention in .NET
 public Patron GetPatronById(string barcode)
 {
     string uri = "patrons/find?barcode=" + barcode;
     var Patron =  GetAsync<Patron>(uri).Result;
     return Patron;
 }
```

*Note*: In the above snippet I assumed that you haven't moved the `GetAsync` into another class. If you move it, then you have to make a slight change.

**Update**

> I'm not following what you mean by your note. Do I need to make GetPatronById a task function as well - like Yuval has done below?

I mean something like this:

```
// The name of the class may be not the most suitable in this case.
public class Repo
{
    public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri)
    {
        var client = GetHttpClient(uri);
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var t = serializer.Deserialize<T>(content);
        return t;
    }
}

public Patron GetPatronById(string barcode)
{
     string uri = "patrons/find?barcode=" + barcode;
     var Patron =  Repo.GetAsync<Patron>(uri).Result;
     return Patron;
}
```

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by your note. Do I need to make GetPatronById a task function as well - like Yuval has done below?

Answer (score 2):

Generic can be easily done with:

```
private async Task<T> GetAsync(string uri)
{
    var client = GetHttpClient(uri);
    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
}
```

Things to note:

1. JavaScriptSerializer has been deprecated for ages, avoid using it. Try out [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead.
2. This:

   ```
   Patron Patron =  GetAsync(uri).Result;
   ```

   is dangerous and can cause potential deadlocks, especially in Web API. You need to go "async all the way":

   ```
   public Task<Patron> GetPatronByIdAsync(string barcode)
   {
      string uri = $"patrons/find?barcode={barcode}";
      return GetAsync<Patron>(uri);
   }
   ```

And only your top most level invoker need `await` on the `Task`. Possibly some controller action:

```
public async Task SomeAction()
{
     await GetPatronByIdAsync("hello");
}
```